# Get the number of Rows returned by a OleDbDataReader ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, row, datareader

After connecting to a database using `DataReader`, how can I count the number of `rows` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Data readers are forward only so they don't have the count when first filled.  You can do several things to address this:

1. Run a separate command to get the count OR using NextResult to help instead of a totally separate command).
2. Loop through the results and count the records
3. Use a DataSet

Here's an example of #1:

Without NextResult:
http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18807

With NextResult (Doesn't return record count but gives you idea of how to use NextResult):
http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/295793-datareader-nextresults-question

Here's an example of #2:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308050

Answer (score 2):

Only by repeatedly calling `Read()`.

A `DataReader` is a forward-only view of a resultset and cannot get a count.